# Taking control of another window with Go

Tags: go

I'm wondering if there are any libraries that help me take control of another window. For example if user has calc.exe running, I'd like my go code to move it, resize it, maybe even remove it's frame, attach stuff to it, idk.

Right now I only know how to do it with scripting languages like autoit or autohotkey or whatnot.

Comment: https://github.com/AllenDang/w32 implements the Win32 API and has all functionality you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are several libraries which can be found using [godoc.org](http://godoc.org) or [go-search.org](http://go-search.org). In this example I'm using [w32](http://github.com/AllenDang/w32) and [w32syscall](http://github.com/hnakamur/w32syscall) (which supplies some additional functions):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/AllenDang/w32"
    "github.com/hnakamur/w32syscall"
)

func main() {
    err := w32syscall.EnumWindows(func(hwnd syscall.Handle, lparam uintptr) bool {
        h := w32.HWND(hwnd)
        text := w32.GetWindowText(h)
        if strings.Contains(text, "Calculator") {
            w32.MoveWindow(h, 0, 0, 200, 600, true)
        }
        return true
    }, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Both of these libraries are merely exposing the underlying win32 API with minimal wrapping, so you will have to read the [corresponding documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft to really know how to use them.

Comment: Thanks. Will I also be able to achieve this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx with the w32 go wrappers?

Comment: Looks like it's defined in the w32 library: http://godoc.org/github.com/AllenDang/w32#DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea

Comment: It returns 0 and doesn't do anything unfortunately, even after I say the frame changed w32.SetWindowPos(h, 0,0, 0, 200, 600, w32.SWP_FRAMECHANGED)